# Is a way to declare common response types to different actions?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I'm developing web api in Asp.net Core 5 and documenting them using Swashbuckle Swagger.

I used:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CustomResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
```

and the comment:

```
/// <response code="200">Ok</response>
```

I did the same for error response:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CustomResult), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
```

and the comment:

```
/// <response code="400">Error</response>
```

It works.

Now suppose that the errors are generated by a method common to several actions (e.g. login in a `BaseCustomController` class).
Do I have to repeat these annotations for each action? Or is there a way to declare them only once?

*Notes: I'm not using Swagger-Core Annotations*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a static class used for api convention type. The convention type can be applied to the whole controller class or to all controller classes in an assembly.

Define the static class that contains just static `void` method. The info it captures is the signatures of the methods (and the attributes applied on the methods). Like this:

```
public static class MyApiConventions {
   //this applies to all methods named "Get" and with one parameter of id
   [ProducesResponseType(typeof(CustomResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
   [ProducesResponseType(typeof(CustomResult), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
   public static void Get(object id){}
}
```

Usually you define the conventions based on the declared method names & signatures (in the conventions class). The `ApiConventionNameMatchAttribute` can be used to define how the declared method name is matched (any, exact, suffix or prefix - the behavior is defined by `ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior`). The `ApiConventionTypeMatchAttribute` can be used on parameters to indicate how the type is matched (any or assignable - the behavior is defined by `ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior`).

You can apply the convention type on a specific controller class:

```
[ApiConventionType(typeof(MyApiConventions))]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : Controller {
   //...
}
```

or globally on all controllers in the current assembly (recommended to define it in the `Startup.cs`):

```
[assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(MyApiConventions))]
namespace ... {
    
}
```

The framework has a default convention type called [DefaultApiConventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.defaultapiconventions).

Note that, it looks like `[ApiController]` is required for the `ApiConventionTypeAttribute` to work (at least that's what designed in `asp.net core 2.2`). I however don't find any documentation talking about that requirement.

More on [Api Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks. In your answer (case of specific controller): methods obviously have different names in the signature. I can't find any docs about Api Conventions in this case. DefaultApiConventions is not right.

Comment: and `/// <response code="500">Any other errors.</response>` in comment for Swagger?

Comment: @Emanuele do you mean different ***parameter names***? The method signature just need to have the same parameter count & compatible type (because we can use `ApiConventionNameMatchAttribute` and `ApiConventionTypeMatchAttribute` as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: `DefaultApiConventions` is just the default class used by the framework. You define your custom one. This is the only way to reuse the conventions as much as possible.

Comment: I think you can reuse the conventions, not the comments. The comments should be written for each specific method and I don't think they can be used as part of some metadata to feed the swagger. Of course that might be wrong but at least it's weird. Remember that swagger is just a tool that may not be used by developers but comments should be written carefully for better documentation, especially for libraries used by developers, the comments will be shown by IDE as instructions to the api usage.

Comment: Different method names not parameter names

Comment: @Emanuele yes of course, as I said, the method names are also used to match against the actual controller method names. But the matching behavior can be controlled by `ApiConventionNameMatchAttribute` so that matching can be any, exact, with prefix or suffix. In case of `any`, the method name will be ignored (so it does not matter what you use for the method name inside the convention class). But the parameters count and type should be matched. If you have a specific scenario to deal with, please update your question with more details so that I can provide a more concrete example.